# Python subprocess Popen not outputting sqlplus error strings

Tags: python-3.x, sqlplus

When I run sqlplus in Python using subprocess I get no output when there are SQL errors, or update or insert statements returning number of rows updated or inserted. When I run select statements with no errors I do get the output.

Here is my code:
This creates a string with newlines that are then written to process.stdin.write()

```
def write_sql_string(process, args):
    sql_commands = ''


    sql_commands += "WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;\n"
    sql_line = '@' + args.sql_file_name

    if crs_debug:
        print('DEBUG: ' + 'sys.argv', ' '.join(sys.argv))

    if len(args.sql_args) > 0:
        len_argv = len(args.sql_args)

        sql_commands += "SET VERIFY OFF\n"

        for i in range(0, len_argv):
            sql_line += ' "' + args.sql_args[i] + '"'

        sql_commands += sql_line + "\n"
#        if prod_env:
        sql_commands += "exit;\n"

    if crs_debug:
        print('DEBUG: ' + 'sql_line: ' + sql_line)

    process.stdin.write(sql_commands)
```

This code executes the SQL commands

```
def execute_sql_file(username, dbpass, args):


    db_conn_str = username + '/' + dbpass + '@' + args.dbname
    # '-S', - Silent
    sqlplus_cmd = ['sqlplus', '-S', '-L', db_conn_str]
    if crs_debug:
        print('DEBUG: ' + ' '.join(sqlplus_cmd))

    process = subprocess.Popen(sqlplus_cmd,
                               stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

    write_sql_string(process, args)

    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
    # Get return code of sql query
    stdout_lines = stdout.split("\n")
    print('STDOUT')
    for line in stdout_lines:
        line = line.rstrip()
        print(line)

    stderr_lines = stderr.split("\n")
    print('STDERR')
    for line in stderr_lines:
        line = line.rstrip()
        print(line)

    sqlplus_rc = process.poll()

    # Check if sqlplus returned an error
    if sqlplus_rc != 0:
        print("FAILURE in " + script_name + " in connecting to Oracle exit code: " + str(sqlplus_rc))
        print(stderr_data)
        sys.exit(sqlplus_rc)
```

When I run I run my code for a SQL file that requires parameters, if I run it with missing parameters I get no output. If I run it with parameters I get the correct output.

Here is an example SQL file sel_dual.sql:

```
SELECT 'THIS IS TEXT &1 &2' FROM dual;
```

As an example command line:

```
run_sql_file.py dbname sql_file [arg1]...[argn]
```

If I run the script with

```
run_sql_file.py dbname sel_dual.py
```

I get no output, even though it should ask for a parameter and give other error output.

If I run the script with

```
run_sql_file.py dbname sel_dual.py Seth F
```

I get the proper output:

```
'THISISTEXTSETHF'
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
THIS IS TEXT Seth F
```

The args referred to is the result of processing args with the argparse module:

```
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Run a SQL file with ptional arguments using SQLPlus')
    parser.add_argument('dbname', help='db (environment) name')
    parser.add_argument('sql_file_name', help='sql file')
    parser.add_argument('sql_args', nargs='*', help='arguments for sql file')
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Does anybody know what could be causing this? I've omitted the rest of the script since it basically gets command arguments and validates that the SQL file exists.

I am running sqlplus version  Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production. I am running Python version 3.7.6. I am running on Linux (not sure what version). The kernel release is 4.1.12-124.28.5.el7uek.x86_64.

Comment: What is "args"? Can you provide the code that parses args?